# Django/Wagtail How to get multiline help_text

Tags: django, wagtail

When working in the admin portal I have found a way to get multi-line help text. It took a long time to find this answer so I figured I would post about it for others to fine.

The secret is the mark_safe

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

item = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, help_text=mark_safe('Line 1 <br />Line 2))
```

Comment: Future info: There's a checkbox right above the 'Review your question' btn that allows you to answer your own question and here's a [StockOverflow Blog Post about answering your own stuff](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions) ..this is probably a better route so the question doesn't show as **open** and without an answer

Answer (score 0):

Nice post.
To even go further you can try markdown for this.

```
mark_safe(render_markdown('Line 1. \nLine 2.  \n**Important** thing.'))
```

Please

Comment: Neat, what is the import for that?

Comment: Hi David, https://pypi.org/project/Markdown/